# Django test for a page that redirects

Tags: django, django-tests

I am trying to write a test for a View that redirects to the **dashboard** but I'm not getting something right. A user must be authenticated before he/she can access the *(membership)* View.
In my **urls.py**, I have something like

```
...
path('membership/', MembershipView.as_view(), name='membership'),
...
```

Then my **tests.py** contains

```
class TestApp(TestCase):
    def test_that_membership_resolves(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.post('/membership/', {
            # I then pass the necessary values in a dictionary
            ...
            ...
        })
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("src:dashboard"))
```

But the I am getting an error which says

```
self.assertEqual(
AssertionError: '/login/?next=%2Fmembership%2F' != '/dashboard'
- /login/?next=%2Fmembership%2F
+ /dashboard
 : Response redirected to '/login/?next=/membership/', expected '/dashboard'Expected '/login/?next=/membership/' to equal '/dashboard'.
```

I think it's telling me to login first. I already have a test a method that tests for login and the test passes. How can I solve this issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just login first after instancing your client. Your view only works by logging in, so you need to login first?

```
client.login(email="testuser1@example.com", password="testpass123")
```

Or whatever user login works in your test setUp

Edit: use a setUp for all your tests, so you have some initial data for all of them:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email="testuser1@example.com",password="testpass123",)
    def test_that_membership_resolves(self):
        client = Client()
        client.login(email="testuser1@example.com", password="testpass123")
        response = client.post('/membership/', {
            # I then pass the necessary values in a dictionary
            ...
            ...
        })
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("src:dashboard"))


    def test_whatever_else_comes_next_to_test(self):
        # use your setUp data again for another test
```