# Django testcase for logout API with LoginRequired mixin, but for anonymous user it is redirecting to login API with ?next= parameter

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, logout

But what if I want to check without login. For example, I have one api logout which is having LoginRequired mixin, I want to test that anyone cannot hit logout if hes not logged in. So I created testcase as below.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_user_logout_logged_in_user(self, client):
    url = reverse('logout')
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 302
    assertRedirects(response, reverse('login'))
```

but I got this error,
AssertionError: '/auth/login-view/?next=%2Fauth%2Flogout-view%2F' != '/auth/login-view/'

Means I get ?next={something for after login api}.

How do I check that redirected api is login api.

My logout api is as below:

```
class LogoutView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
"""
description: This is user logout view.
GET request will log out user and redirects to home page.
"""
def get(self, request):
    return LogoutService.logout_user(request=request)


class LogoutService:
@staticmethod
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_SUCCESS)
    return redirect('home')
```

[Django test for a page that redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69958013/django-test-for-a-page-that-redirects)

I tried this answer, but it is for logged-in user. I want to test for un authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test that a view redirects with the "next" parameter correctly you need to add the next get parameter to the login URL when testing

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_login_required_redirect(self, client):
    url = reverse('someview')
    response = client.get(url)
    assertRedirects(response, f"{reverse('login')}?next={url}")
```

Don't use `LoginRequiredMixin` for your logout view, you set next to your logout view this way and that will cause the user to instantly logout after they login - handle the redirect manually in your view

```
class LogoutView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        return LogoutService.logout_user(request=request)
```

Comment: But Is their any other way to check that its login url with next parameter? Because this solution is last option as I have used LoginRequiredMixin in all project, and I have to check this type of functionality for all views. For example, If unauthenticated user access to home page, it should be redirected to login page with next parameter so that after login it will redirect to certain page(for this case, its home page) from its originated. Appreciated for answer.

Comment: @Parth added a generic way to test that the next parameter is correct when a view redirects to the login page. If you use the LoginRequiredMixin in your logout view you will cause the user to instantly logout after they login as they will be redirected to the logout page again